# Linq extending Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to write a generic wildcard Search for the ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpressionVisitor that has the following signature:

```
public static SqlExpressionVisitor<T> WhereWildcardSearch<T> (this SqlExpressionVisitor<T> ev, Expression<Func<T,string>> field, string search)
```

where ev is the rest of the filter, field is the getter for the field to search by and search is the entered term.

Normally (non-generic) I would write the following:

```
if(search.StartsWith('*') && search.EndsWith('*')) 
    ev = ev.Where(x => x.foo.Contains(search.Trim('*')));
```

and of course also variants for x.foo.StartsWith or EndsWith.

Now I am searching for something like (pseudocode:)

```
ev = ev.Where(x => field(x).Contains(search.Trim('*')));
```

Of course I can't compile and call the expression directly, as this should be translated to Sql using Linq2Sql.

This is my code so far:

```
var getFieldExpression = Expression.Invoke (field, Expression.Parameter (typeof (T), "getFieldParam"));
var searchConstant = Expression.Constant (search.Trim('*'));

var inExp = Expression.Call (getFieldExpression, typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains"), searchConstant);
var param = Expression.Parameter (typeof (T), "object");
var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>> (inExp, param);

ev = ev.Where (exp);
```

Please don't tell me that I should directly write SQL with `$"LIKE %search%"` or something - I know that there are other ways, but solving this would help my understanding of Linq and Expressions in general and it bugs me when I can't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how it can be done (I think it will be clear for you without much additional explanations what you did wrong, but if not - feel free to request a clarification):

```
// extract property name from passed expression
var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)field.Body).Member.Name;            
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "object");            
var searchConstant = Expression.Constant(search.Trim('*'));
var contains = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains");
// object.FieldName.Contains(searchConstant)
var inExp = Expression.Call(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName), contains, searchConstant);            
// object => object.FieldName.Contains(searchConstant)
var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(inExp, param);
```

In response to comment. You have two expression trees: one is being passed to you and another one which you are building (`exp`). In this simple case they both use the same number of parameters and those parameters are of the same type (`T`). In this case you can reuse parameter from `field` expression tree, like this:

```
// use the same parameter
var param = field.Parameters[0];
var searchConstant = Expression.Constant(search.Trim('*'));
var contains = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains");            
// note field.Body here. Your `field` expression is "parameter => parameter.Something"
// but we need just "parameter.Something" expression here
var inExp = Expression.Call(field.Body, contains, searchConstant);
// pass the same parameter to new tree
var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(inExp, param);
```

In more complicated cases you might need to use `ExpressionVisitor` to replace parameters in one expression tree to reference to parameters from another (final) expression tree.

Comment: This works perfeclty fine, and is exactly what I asked for. Thanks!

Just a further question: This will only work when a Field-Getter Expression is passed (like I asked). Is there an easy modification that would work with any Expression<Func<T, string>>? (assuming that the given expression is valid in linq2sql)

Comment: understood it now. Thank you!